# Should I flag suspiciously upvoted questions?

Tags: discussion, flags, voting-fraud

A few times recently I have found questions that are difficult to make sense of, often by lower rep users and receive 3 or more upvotes very quickly. I flagged one recently that got 5 upvotes when it was almost indecipherable (I described it as possible abuse and it was marked as helpful) but I'm not sure whether I should be flagging a question just because of how many votes it has.

Comment: You're not flagging *just* because of how many votes the question has, but because the votes look suspicious. It is reasonable to ask a moderator to investigate a suspicious voting pattern. As long as you're not  crying wolf too often...

Comment: i see that quite a bit too. someone posts a terrible question and asks all his coworkers to upvote.